# how do I make JavaScript run after the page is loaded

Tags: 8, javascript

With Drupal 8, I am adding JavaScript to my theme in the libraries.yml so that I can put lift segments into the data layer.  But it is running before the body is loaded, and the data layer is being overwritten.

How can I make this script run after the body load?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Did you use `$(document).ready` or better `Drupal.behaviors`?

This is from drupal docs:

> When using jQuery it is standard for a large majority of situations to
>   wrap almost all code inside the $(document).ready() function, like
>   this:
>
> ```
> $(document).ready(function () {
>   // Do some fancy stuff.
> });
> ```
>
> This ensures that our code will only run after the DOM has loaded and
>   all elements are available. However with Drupal there is an alternate
>   better method; using the functionality of Drupal.behaviors and once().
>   If used properly this will ensure that your code runs both on normal
>   page loads and when data is loaded by AJAX. The Drupal.behaviors
>   object is itself a property of the Drupal object, and when we want our
>   module/theme to add new jQuery behaviors, the best method is to simply
>   extend this object.
>
> A really basic example:
>
> ```
> Drupal.behaviors.myBehavior = {
>   attach: function (context, settings) {
>     // Using once() to apply the myCustomBehaviour effect when you want to do just run one function.
>     $(context).find('input.myCustomBehavior').once('myCustomBehavior').addClass('processed');
>     // ... left out the more complex examples
>   }
> };
> ```

Quote from [JavaScript API in Drupal 8](https://www.drupal.org/node/2269515)

Comment: This is working for me, today; 
 `(function ($, Drupal, drupalSettings) {
  Drupal.behaviors.domo =  {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      $(document, context).once('domo').each( function() {
        $(document).ready(function () {
          onsswitch_init();
        });  '
    }
  }
}`